# Android - Are singletons destroyed when no object uses them?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm currently trying to implement a repository pattern in my app but I am little confused how the lifecycle of a singleton object works in Android. So I have a companion object that I download some data in and when the data is downloaded, the MutableLiveData object has 30 items in the array. If I then switch tabs and come back to my fragment a little later, it then has 0 items again. Is this the way it's supposed to be?

In my viewModel I create a variable like this:

```
private val newsRepository = NewsRepository
```

and the start of the class looks like this:

```
class NewsRepository {
  companion object {
     private val mainRepository = MainRepository(ApiHelper(RetrofitBuilder.apiService))
    
     var news: MutableLiveData<MutableList<Item>> = MutableLiveData()
   }
 }
```

Comment: "Are singletons destroyed when no object uses them?" -- no. "Is this the way it's supposed to be?" -- there may be a bug in parts of your code that are not included in your question. I would start by making `news` be a `val` (not a `var`) and by making it be a `MutableLiveData<List<Item>>`. Both your `var` and your `MutableList` are "code smells" in this context, and changing those to be less-mutable variants may help you uncover bugs in your implementation.

Comment: When you say you *"switch tabs and come back to the fragment later"* are you saying you move to another part of your app, or that you're putting the app in the background and using something else? If it's going in the background there's a chance the process is getting destroyed, and if you're not persisting that data then it'll be reinitialised next time you open the app (since the whole thing is being recreated). If the app is still on-screen the whole time, you should post the code where you actually set the data on `news`

Comment: @CommonsWare That actually solved it. Thank you so much. I come from iOS so I'm a little confused by many things in Kotlin